# Rails 3 - new controller action route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing

I have an app with online trainings and every online training has several chapters. I don't want to create next controller just for training chapters. I want to have new action in TrainingsController which might be called chapter. Then I want URL like this:

/trainings/1/chapter/3

(/controller/id of training/action/id of chapter)

Could you please help me how can I set routes.rb to achieve this behaviour? I tried lot of things, but it's still broken.

Thank you in advance!

Petr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could define the route as:

```
resources :trainings do 
  get 'chapter/:chapter_id', action: :chapter, as: :training_chapter, constraints: { chapter_id: /\d+/ }
end
```

Then in your `trainings_controller.rb`:

```
def chapter
  # params[:chapter_id]
  ...
end
```

The line `get 'chapter/:chapter_id', action: :chapter, as: training_chapter, constraints: { chapter_id: /\d+/ }`, defines a `get` route of format `training/:id/chapter/:chapter_id` which executes the `chapter` action in `TrainingController`.

The name of this route is `training_chapter` defined by `as: :training_chapter`, so you can use the named route helpers such as `training_chapter_trainings_path`.

The final option `constraints: /\d+/` is restricting the values that `chapter_id` can hold, based on which this route gets executed.  So, a get request to `/trainings/1/chapter/1` executes the `chapter` action, whereas `/trainings/1/chapter/a` does not because the value `a` for `chapter_id` is non-digit.

Answer (score 1):

I think here is what you are looking for:

```
match '/trainings/:training_id/chapter/:chapter_id' => 'trainings#chapter', :as => 'chapter_training'
```

---

app/controllers/trainings_controller.rb

```
def chapter
end
```